# All bundles load on every page load React + Java

Tags: java, reactjs, lazy-loading, html-webpack-plugin, code-splitting

I have react + java application.

I have used lazy loading to spilt the pages in multiple js blocks.

Multiple entries are present in index.html in script tag:

```
<body>
    <div id="react"></div>
    <script src="/static/built/0.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/built/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/built/1.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/built/2.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/built/3.bundle.js"></script>
    .....
    <script src="/static/built/10.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I load any page all the bundles get load. I want only the bundle which the js page is using to get loaded.

Can anyone pls suggest me any good approach.?

Thanks!!

Comment: You have provided zero information about how your app is split up. So start reading here https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html and see if the suits your needs.

Comment: @Strelok I have mentioned that i have used lazy loading for splitting the bundles and I have tagged html-webpack-plugin as well. The link which you have mentioned gives very basic info on code-splitting. Thanks :)